# Python sketch to sketch microstructure

Tags: python, random, graphics, spline, sketching

[Microstructure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRlxr.png)

Hi guys,
I have to use Python code to generate a random sketch like the picture attached. The objects inside represent particles in a rectangular matrix. Does anyone have any ideas on how such a sketch can be generated?
I haven't started working, but looking for ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.